# Vim folding on Python functions

Tags: python, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I try to fold on Python functions, not on indent.
Is there a build in method or Regex-rule I can use?
(Solved further down)

This is my code so far:

```
set foldmethod=indent
nnoremap <space> za
vnoremap <space> zf
```

Two last lines is for open/closing with Space.

The top/black-version is what I try to accomplish. Overlapping terminal is my version (+styling)
[image]
(From [Fast.ai - Lesson 3: Deep Learning 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9C06ZPF8Uuc&t=6761s))

Complete with styling:

```
set foldmethod=indent
nnoremap <space> za
vnoremap <space> zf
syntax on
colorscheme desert
```

(How to change the global-config in Vim: 'cd ~' and 'vim .vimrc')

---

Solution from [python-mode](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/):

```
cd ~/.vim/pack/foo/start
git clone https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode.git
cd python-mode
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

And this line in ~/.vimrc to enable closing with space

```
nnoremap <space> za
```

Could be that you have to create all the folders in ~/.vim/pack/foo/start

My result:
[image: result]

Comment: Regex can't parse everything.

Comment: If you can't find it here, you might want to ask on [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).  Be sure to read their rules beforehand though.

Comment: user202729, do you have examples where it can't parse?

Comment: [HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: user202729, HTML-parsing is a different problem than this example. I don't see how your example would limit parsing functions in Python, even if they include HTML.

Comment: No difference. Regex can't parse HTML, regex can't parse Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excellent [python-mode](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/) plug-in [folds](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/blob/develop/ftplugin/python/pymode.vim#L59) on its own, more advanced [expression](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/blob/develop/autoload/pymode/folding.vim#L47), by default. It produces the results in your screenshot.